# How to Save Datalist Permantly with Appended Option

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a website, one section of the website is for users to either select an existing `TesterName` or enter a new one.

```js
var curTester;

function SetTesterName() {
  var Value = document.getElementById("testerNameInput").value;

  if (!Value) return;

  if ( $("#testerNameList").find("option[value='" + Value + "']").length == 0 ) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = Value;
    document.getElementById('testerNameList').appendChild(option);
    alert('New tester name added');
  }

  curTester = Value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="testerNameInput" >Tester Name</label>         
<input id = "testerNameInput" list = "testerNameList" name = "testerNameInput" type = "text" style="width: 70%"/>
<datalist id="testerNameList">
  <option value="Name1">
  <option value="Name2">
  <option value="Name3">
</datalist>

<button onclick="SetTesterName()">Submit</button>
```

This 2 pieces of code work fine, but when I reload the webpage and look into the datalist, the new appended option is missing. What should I do?

Comment: take a look at localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to solve only frontend you can use localStorage for this problem.

If you want users to see what has been
added by other users, you need a backend to handle database operations.

i edit your snippet. you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k9hxyv5z/1/)

```
var curTester;
var testerNameList = localStorage.getItem('testerNameList');

function SetTesterName() {
    var Value = $('#testerNameInput').val()

    if (!Value) return;

    if ( $("#testerNameList").find("option[value='" + Value + "']").length == 0 ) {
        // var option = document.createElement("option");
        // option.value = Value;
        // document.getElementById('testerNameList').appendChild(option);
        // you can use short way like below
        $('#testerNameList').append($(`<option value="` + Value + `"></option>`))
        testerNameList = localStorage.getItem('testerNameList');
        if(!testerNameList){ // localStorage empty
            localStorage.setItem('testerNameList', JSON.stringify([Value]));
        }else{
            let arr = JSON.parse(testerNameList)
            arr.push(Value)
            console.log(arr)
            localStorage.setItem('testerNameList', JSON.stringify(arr));
        }
        alert('New tester name added');
    }

    curTester = Value;
}

// When the page is ready it adds the elements found in the local storage.
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    if(testerNameList != null){
        JSON.parse(testerNameList).forEach(x => {
            $('#testerNameList').append($(`<option value="` + x + `"></option>`))
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, your demo is exactly what I want. When I tried your demo, I pressed `F12` and selected the `Application` tab, and click `Local Storage` and I could see everything I tried to append earlier, however when I tested it locally with local host, nothing is written to `Local Storage`, any ideas why?

Comment: Edit your question and share the screenshot of Local Storage in Developer tools.

Comment: Somehow I reload my code and it works fine now. No modification was made. Thank you, I will mark your answer as `accepted`.

Comment: The software world is full of mysteries :)